# Array of array of multiple strings

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create an array of array of strings, something like this:

```
let rules : type = [
 ["N"]
 ["N", "N"]
 ["N", "N", "N"]
]
```

But I couldn't set the type. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several options here. The best way to go would be as true arrays of arrays:

```
let rules : string[][] = [
 ["N"],
 ["N", "N"],
 ["N", "N", "N"]
];
```

or

```
let rules : Array<Array<string>> = [
 ["N"],
 ["N", "N"],
 ["N", "N", "N"]
];
```

You can also type it using single-element [tuple types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#tuple-types), but that's not really the intended usage of tuple types:

```
let rules : [string[]] = [
 ["N"],
 ["N", "N"],
 ["N", "N", "N"]
];
```

or

```
let rules : [string][] = [
 ["N"],
 ["N", "N"],
 ["N", "N", "N"]
];
```

or

```
let rules : [[string]] = [
 ["N"],
 ["N", "N"],
 ["N", "N", "N"]
];
```

Comment: Or maybe Array<Array<string>>

Comment: Or Array<string[]>.  Or Array<string>[].  Or [Array<string>].  Or... :)